Is it possible to do multiple substitions in Visual select mode?
This way works fine for multiple substitution in normal mode
:%s/string1/string2/e | %s/string3/string4/e

How to make something similar in "visual mode select" (Shift+V)?
I have tried
:'<,'>s/string1/string2/e | s/string3/string4/e

But it replaces only the first occurrence.

You need to repeat the '< and '> marks like this:
:'<,'>s/string1/string2/e | '<,'>s/string3/string4/e

This works because '< and '> expand to the last selected Visual area as explained in :help '<.
In other words: even though the Visual selection will be gone, the marks will still point to the right lines.
The :* range is a neat shortcut to repeat the last Visual range, shortening the command above to:
:'<,'>s/string1/string2/e | *s/string3/string4/e

Refer to :help :star for more information.

I prefer typing * on the second range because it’s short and easier. It’s a neat little synonym

@D.BenKnoble very neat, indeed. I didn't know about it. I will edit it into my answer but I'd prefer to upvote yours.

Not to distract from the existing answer, but… you already have the answer before your eyes.
You want to do the same as this:
:%s/string1/string2/e | %s/string3/string4/e
 ^                      ^

where both commands start with a range, % for "whole buffer", but for the visual selection.
Since you already have the visual range '<,'> in the first command, then it should be repeated for the second command, like in your reference command:
:'<,'>s/string1/string2/e | '<,'>s/string3/string4/e
 ^^^^^                      ^^^^^


"Not to distract from the existing answer" - I think it's fair to say you failed on this account :-D

@Friedrich https://i.imgur.com/24m0ubM.png

If you're not afraid of a bit of redundancy, you can do something like this:
:[range]s#\v(string1|string3)#\s={'string1': 'string2', 'string3': 'string4'}[submatch(0)]#e

Yes, this is quite overkill. However, if you often have to do this, it can be used as a start for defining a new command, that could be used with e.g.:
:[range]TrString#string1|string3#string2|string4#e

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim for ideas how such a command could be implemented.
